# washing machine doesn't spin

Tags: repair, washing-machine

I have a Haier HLP23E washing machine. Last week it stops to spin. After draining all water, instead of start the spin cycle, it stops for a while and then start to pour in the water. I switch off the power, turn it on and start the spin cycle again after all water drained out. This time, I hear humming, just like the motor is spinning but the inner tub doesn't follow. Someone said the motor burned but it works perfectly in washing cycle. It is also suggested that the door switch doesn't work but the washing cycle is working well if the door switch problem shall it have the warning during the washing cycle also, so I don't think the switch is bad. By trying to start the spin cycle several times, I some times hears the noise like a stucking gear. Does any one have any idea how to diagnose the real problem of the washing machine? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The humming is the drain pump, not the motor.

You probably have an electrical problem - some wire someplace is broken (probably a wire going to the motor, perhaps a sense wire, or for high speed power). I had this happen to me and diagnosis said to replace the main control board for $$$.

But before doing that I checked it closely and found a cracked solder join (i.e. one wire was not making a good connect). I reflowed the solder and all was well.

But I did this myself - and it took a long time. For you to pay someone to check this for you will probably cost more than just getting someone who does this for a living to just diagnose and fix it.

Unless you are really good friends with someone handy? Usually if you take apart the machine it will have documentation telling you how to diagnose it.

First thing to do after following the instructions on the documentation is carefully check each wire going to the motor, and check the board where the wire goes for a loose connection.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just open the case and have the power for the air pump unplugged but there is still some humming. With the air pump plugged and when I switch on the SPIN mode, I can hear it's trying to suck the water out but not works well. Do you think the pump doesn't work also? BTW, it seems that the water will drain out even I unplug the power line for the pump?

Comment: So perhaps you did not actually unplug the pump, you unplugged something else. Unplugging random things is not the right way to fix this. Use the documentation it comes with, and follow it *exactly*.

Comment: I am sure it is the pump, which it is written on the label, also, I search the part store online and they shows me the same model that I saw http://www.repairclinic.com/Shop-For-Parts/a11b198c36d682367/Model-HLP23E-Haier-Washing-Machine-Pump-Parts . I just unplug the power line.

Comment: So you are saying that you unplugged the pump, but when it ran it pumped out water? That means you did not unplug it. But it makes no difference - why do you care about the pump when the problem is the motor?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like this washer has a transmission in it, so that narrows the problem down.

The problem is most likely the belt. According to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1jE0J-86klc), the belt is a common size so you can just take it to the hardware store or an auto parts store and get something similar. Or order one online somewhere for $5.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I saw that the machine have only one belt. However, the washing cycle is working great, so can we say that the belt is working fine?

Comment: It's possible that the belt only slips at high speeds. And besides, considering the cost of replacing our fixing any other part of them machine, it's worth trying this cheap part first.

Comment: makes sense. I am going to order the belt to try. By the way, what happens if I take the belt off and turn the SPIN mode on, am I suppose to see the motor wheel's rotating?

Comment: Thats what I would expect.

Comment: It's not the belt, don't waste your money ordering one. It doesn't "slip" at high speed.

Comment: Hi Ariel, if it is not the belt, what else do you suggest to check? Thanks.

Comment: @user1285419 I already told you: There is probably a broken wire to the motor, or to some sensor.